# Grep 2 different requirements in one command line statement

Tags: grep

How would I print the last 3 lines that have the string `#include` from `tester.c` and if fewer than 3 lines contain the string, print *the entire file*.

So far I have:

```
grep "#include" tester.c | tail -3
```

But I can't figure out how to include the second half of the requirement. This is homework and the solution must be a single line with no `;` which is why I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please include your input and expected output.

Comment: the input is any average C program and the output should be the last 3 lines that have "#include". If however 3 lines cannot be found with "#include", then the whole file is printed.

Comment: @Johnny please [edit] your question to provide additional information. Comments eventually get lost.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -3` will not print more than 3 lines; it prints 3 or fewer. So if 'grep' finds 3 or fewer matching lines, tail will pass them ALL to the stdout. If there are more than 3 matches, `tail` will limit them to 3 lines only.

You have solved your problem before even posting it here as your command does exactly what you need...

That's what happens when you're working at night :)

EDIT: I probably misread your problem..

If you want to  print the WHOLE FILE when <3 matches found - just run

```
f="testfile.c" && C=3 && [ $(grep -c "#include" ${f}) -lt ${C} ] && cat ${f} || grep "#include" ${f} |tail -${C}
```

However if you're working on a possibly slow FS (e.g., NFS) or you're dealing with files having LOTS of lines or lines are extremely long, this might be too slow for you as you have to read the file twice..

```
f="testfile.c" && C=3 && CONTENT=$(cat "${f}") && MATCHES=$(echo "$CONTENT"|grep "#include"|tail -${C}) && [ $(echo "$MATCHES" | wc -l) -lt ${C} ] && echo "$CONTENT" || echo "$MATCHES"
```

This way you'll have to open and read the file only once BUT you'll have it buffered in RAM (which is much faster than storage devices). If you're low on RAM or buffering the file there is too  expensive for you, use the first command [where file is opened twice]; it's slower, but it won't crash the OS or your application (although the risk of getting process stuck in 'D' state is higher... and it's no good for the OS either..)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lines=$(grep "#include" tester.c);
   test $(echo $lines | wc -l) -ge 3 && {echo $lines | head -n 3} || cat tester.c;
       unset lines
```

Note: this solution can by typed as one line.  I have separated it into multiple lines for readability only.

**EDIT**

In response to the comments, I suppose you could replace the semicolons with `&&` to make the line be

```
lines=$(grep "#include" tester.c) &&
   test $(echo $lines | wc -l) -ge 3 && {echo $lines | head -n 3} || cat tester.c
```

This isn't technically wrong, but it leaves `lines` set.  Also the `&&` is unnecessary, but it's fine.

This modified solution still has the advantage that you don't read the file twice like in some of the other solutions.

If you can't use `test`, you could instead use brackets like this:

```
lines=$(grep "#include" tester.c) &&
   [ $(echo $lines | wc -l) -ge 3 ] && {echo $lines | head -n 3} || cat tester.c
```

You can even remove the curly braces:

```
lines=$(grep "#include" tester.c) &&
   [ $(echo $lines | wc -l) -ge 3 ] && echo $lines | head -n 3 || cat tester.c
```

One of these variations ought to meet your requirements.

Comment: I have been able to do it with ";" but I can't seem to figure out how to do it without the ";" as I need the command to only be in 1 line. Any idea?

Comment: This solution is meant to be typed as one line.  I separated it into multiple lines only for readability.  Note that each line ends with `;`.  The `;` is actually necessary when you write this as one line.

Comment: Oh sorry, by one line I meant that I am not allowed to use ";" as separators at all.

Comment: Not *allowed*?  What does that mean?

Comment: That he's supposed to do this in one pipeline? OP, you should tell us what commands you may use.

Comment: grep, ls, egrep, cat, tail, head, echo, wc, cut, sort, uniq

Comment: @Johnny, it's homework?

Comment: @Johnny Try the modified expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like Sildoreth says without the ";" like this:

```
test $(echo `grep "#include" tester.c` | wc -l) -ge 3 && {echo `grep "#include" tester.c` | head -n 3} || cat tester.c
```

Comment: We haven't learned test so I don't think I am allowed to use it.

Comment: *Much* less efficient; but yes, that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd question, especially considering that the command you put forth in the original post does exactly what you want it to?

For example, in file.c, there are 15 lines that match the grep expression:

`% grep -c "#include" file.c
 15
 % grep "#include" file.c | head -18   #(more than the number of matches)
 #include <sys/blah.h>
 #include <sys/blah2.h>
 #include <sys/blah3.h>
 #include <sys/blah4.h>
 #include <sys/blah5.h>
 #include <sys/blah6.h>
 #include <sys/blah7.h>
 #include <sys/blah8.h>
 #include <sys/blah9.h>
 #include <sys/blah10.h>
 #include <sys/blah11.h>
 #include <sys/blah12.h>
 #include <sys/blah13.h>
 #include <sys/blah14.h>
 #include <sys/blah15.h>`

OR

`% grep "#include" file.c | tail -18
 #include <sys/blah.h>
 #include <sys/blah2.h>
 #include <sys/blah3.h>
 #include <sys/blah4.h>
 #include <sys/blah5.h>
 #include <sys/blah6.h>
 #include <sys/blah7.h>
 #include <sys/blah8.h>
 #include <sys/blah9.h>
 #include <sys/blah10.h>
 #include <sys/blah11.h>
 #include <sys/blah12.h>
 #include <sys/blah13.h>
 #include <sys/blah14.h>
 #include <sys/blah15.h>`

Please explain how this does NOT conform to the parameters of your assignment?

Comment: It needs to also meet the requirement that if there are less than 3 results found, the whole file should be printed

Comment: Doh! I [obviously] missed that...

Answer (score 0):

With one pass and with one command and on a GNU system and enough memory to store the whole file content, and you don't care about the order of those last 3 include lines, you could do:

```
awk '{c=c$0RT}/#include/{l[n++%3]=$0RS}END{printf"%s",(n>=3?l[0]l[1]l[2]:c)}' file.c
```